# Brezis-Kato regularity argument - Some questions about Struwe's proof Part II

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

The following is in Appendix B of Struwe's *Variational Methods*

Let $u$ be a solution of $-\Delta u = g(x, u(x))$ in a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$, $N \geq 3$, where $g$ is a Carathéodory function with subcritical superlinear growth.

> **Theorem**:
> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$ be a smooth open set  and let $g: \Omega \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a Carathéodory function such that
> $$
> |g(x, u(x))| \leq a(x)(1 + |u(x)|) \quad \text{ a.e. in } \Omega
> $$
> for some $0 \leq a \in L_{loc}^{N/2}(\Omega)$. Let $u \in H^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ be a weak solution to $-\Delta u = g(x, u)$. Then $u \in L^q_{loc}(\Omega)$ for all $1 < q < \infty$. If $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $a \in L^{N/2}(\Omega)$, then $u \in L^q(\Omega)$ for all $1 < q < \infty$.

The proof goes as follows:

Take $\eta \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, $s \geq 0$ and $L \geq 0$ and let
$$
\varphi = u \min \{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \eta^2 \in H_0^1(\Omega)
$$
Testing the equation against $\varphi$ yields
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 \min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \eta^2 \ dx + \frac s2 \int_{\{|u|^s\leq L \}} |\nabla(|u|^2)|^2 |u|^{2s - 2} \eta ^2 \ dx \\
\leq -2 \int_\Omega \nabla u u \min \{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \nabla \eta \eta \ dx + \int_\Omega a(1 + 2|u|^2)\min \{|u|^{2s}, L^2\}\eta^2 \ dx \\
 (*) \quad {\leq} \frac 12 \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 \min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\}\eta^2 \ dx + c \int_\Omega |u|^2 \min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} |\nabla \eta|^2 \ dx \\
\quad + 3 \int_\Omega a|u|^2 \min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \eta^2 \ dx + \int_\Omega |a|\eta^2 \ dx 
$$

Why does $(*)$ hold?

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Comment: Have you tried to apply Young's inequality, i.e. $xy\leq \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}x^2+\frac 1{\epsilon^2}y^2$? That's what it looks like at first glance, though it might take some time to figure out what $x$, $y$ and $\epsilon$ should be.

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you very much (for this comment and the other answer). I didn't think about Young's inequality here yet, will surely give it a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this with the hint by MaoWao and the help of David Stolnicki.

Recall Young's Inequality with an epsilon:
$$
ab \leq \frac 1{2\varepsilon} a^2 + \frac \varepsilon2 b^2.
$$
We apply this inequality to the first term, which gives
\begin{align*}
- 2 \int_\Omega \nabla u u \min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \nabla \eta \eta \ dx \leq & \frac 12 \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 \min \{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \eta^2 \ dx \\
& + c \int_\Omega u^2 \min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} |\nabla \eta|^2 \ dx.
\end{align*}
As for the second term, we can estimate it as
\begin{align*}
\int_\Omega a(1+|u|^2 \min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \eta^2 \ dx = & \int_\Omega a \min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \eta^2 \ dx  \\
& + 2 \int_\Omega a |u|^2 \min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \eta^2 \ dx \\
= & 3 \int_\Omega a|u|^2 \min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \eta^2 \ dx \\
& + \int_\Omega a\min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \eta^2 (1 - |u|^2) \ dx \\
\leq & 3 \int_\Omega a|u|^2 \min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \eta^2 \ dx \\
& + \int_\Omega a \eta^2 \ dx.   
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
& \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 \min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \eta^2 \ dx + \frac s2 \int_{\{|u|^s\leq L \}} |\nabla(|u|^2)|^2 |u|^{2s - 2} \eta ^2 \ dx \\
& \qquad \leq \frac 12 \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 \min \{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \eta^2 \ dx + c \int_\Omega u^2 \min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} |\nabla \eta|^2 \ dx  \\
& \qquad \quad + 3 \int_\Omega a|u|^2 \min\{|u|^{2s}, L^2\} \eta^2 \ dx + \int_\Omega a \eta^2 \ dx.
\end{split}
\end{align}